# Why does the HTML form element define the window.submit JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit

I found a behavior that I don't understand while debugging my JavaScript code.

By having a `form` element in my HTML, the `window.submit` JavaScript variable is being automatically populated with a reference to the form's submit button.

I am unfamiliar with this behavior and tried my best to google why the form element is defining the JavaScript variable. Is there part of the HTML spec that describes this behavior?

---

Live demo - you can see that the variable starts out as `undefined`, then after the `form` in the HTML, the variable points to the form's submit button. Why?

```html
<script>
  console.log(window.submit); // Shows "undefined" in console
</script>
<form id="form">
  <label for="message">Message:</label>
  <input type="text" id="message">
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
</form>
<script>
  console.log(window.submit); // Shows the above "button" element in console
</script>
```

Comment: You are seeing [this behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3434388/139010).

Comment: @MattBall Thank you. Just when I thought that JavaScript couldn't get any weirder. Voting to close this as dupe, but hopefully it will stick around in case someone else googles this question the way that I did.

Comment: It's not really a duplicate _question_ though... but ok. And it's not really a JS quirk – JS is just a language. It's a weird DOM/HTML thing.

Comment: @MattBall Eh, it's close enough IMO. Basically the thread you linked answers my question perfectly (thanks again), and duplicate flags are really more about "is this basically the same thing" than "was the exact same question asked".